# Is $E^{quasiP}$ equal $E$ or larger?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Let $quasiP$ be the quasipolynomial time complexity class.

1. Is $E^{quasiP}=E$ false?
2. Is $E^{DTIME(2^{(\log n)^k})}=E$ false at every $k>1$?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well $E$ can run in exponential time and so it seems even $E^P$ is not $E$ if $P$ is not in linear time but was not sure.

Comment: We know that P is not in linear time – that follows from the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: So is $E^P\neq E$?

Comment: You can try proving this using the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Then why is $E^{PH}\neq E$ known?

Comment: Perhaps the proof fails.

Comment: Can you give a reference for $E^{\mathit{PH}}$ vs. $E$?

Comment: Sorry I am confused now so even $E^P\neq E$ known?

Comment: Try proving it using the time hierarchy theorem. Does the proof work? Does it fail?

Comment: I saw this in wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity). That is why I asked. What if PH is in quasiP? Would E^PH collapse? I was not even sure E^P is E is correct.

'They also showed that P = BPP if the exponential-time hierarchy, which is defined in terms of the polynomial hierarchy and E as EPH, collapses to E; however, note that the exponential-time hierarchy is usually conjectured not to collapse.'.

Comment: The notation $\mathsf{E^{PH}}$ doesn't refer to $\mathsf{E}$ with a $\mathsf{PH}$ oracle. It refers to the [exponential hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_hierarchy).

Comment: I see. Still I am unsure about E with PH oracle if PH is in quasiP. It seems since E can run in exp time it can pass exp long inputs to P Oracle and since P is not in linear time the total time could be 2^{n^c} at any c>1 and so E^P is not E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $T(n) = n^{\omega(1)}$, and consider the complexity class $\mathsf{E}^{\mathsf{DTIME}(T(n))}$. Given a Turing machine $M$ and an input $x$ of length $n$, an $\mathsf{E}^{\mathsf{DTIME}(T(n))}$ machine can write $1^{2^n}$ and then ask the oracle whether $M$ halts on $x$ within $T(2^n)/\log T(2^n) = 2^{\omega(n)}$ steps. This cannot be done in $\mathsf{E}$ according to the time-hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Is it the same answer in my last comment?

Comment: It's the same idea.

Comment: Haven't you showed P is BPP? Since you showed $E^{PH}$ does not collapse?

Comment: Certainly not .

Comment: How so? If E with P oracle is not E then what is missing?

Comment: My proof doesn't work with $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: I see so PH is quasiP is not going to imply P is BPP. Correct? So E^P is possibly E? Btw why is there a log factor?

Comment: The log is because simulating a Turing machine costs something.

Comment: As for the rest of your question, I'm afraid I don't know much about structural complexity theory.

Comment: Where is the reference for it? Why not a superlogarithmic factor?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem

Comment: Hmm where does it talk about the logarithmic factor?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to read the entire entry. It's not that long.